# How can I send raw binary ping data through a websocket using websocket-client python package?

Tags: python, websocket

So I'm using the Websocket-Client Python Package to get some information and from time to time I need to send a ping to the server so he know I'm alive the problem is that when I create the function that reads the message and then sends the ping back, the recieved ping and the sent ping are different:

This is the message I'm recieving and sending (the logs are obtained using the enableTrace flag to True in the WebsocketApp class).

```
++Rcv raw: b'\x81\x0b{"type":6}\x1e'
++Rcv decoded: fin=1 opcode=1 data=b'{"type":6}\x1e'
++Sent raw: b'\x81\x8bbr\xa1\xe3\x19P\xd5\x9a\x12\x17\x83\xd9T\x0f\xbf'
++Sent decoded: fin=1 opcode=1 data=b'{"type":6}\x1e'
```

I want to send the same raw *b'\x81\x0b{"type":6}\x1e'* bits through the websocket but as you can see it encodes it in some way and the server disconects me.

This is the code I'm using:

```
if _message["type"] == 6: #Filter the message with the type 6 (6 means ping from the server)
    wsapp.send('{"type":6}' + '\x1e') #Send back a pong message (6 also is a pong if the client sends it)
```

I know there is a function in the websocket class from this package (websocket.send_binary(*binary_message*)) but it sends the same data to the server as if I was sending it with the normal send function.

I've also seen that every time I send that same string (*'{"type":6}' + '\x1e'*) there is a different raw message sent to the websocket.

Thank you!

Comment: Your call to `wsapp.send()` is sending a string. If you want to send bytes, send bytes: b'{"type":6}\x1e' . Note the `b` prefix. It's important.

Comment: Still the same problem, when sending using `wsapp.send(b'{"type":6}\x1e')` im getting:
`++Sent raw: b'\x81\x8b\x10Mz\x94ko\x0e\xed(X\xae&0d'

++Sent decoded: fin=1 opcode=1 data=b'{"type":6}\x1e'
`